# How to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for $\sqrt{xy} = 1$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

What approach would be ideal in finding $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for $\sqrt{xy} = 1$?

Comment: Differentiating would be the ideal approach. It doesn't really matter when you do, you just have to do it sometime. Often, it's easier to differentiate straight away rather than, for example, rearranging the equation to solve for $y$ before differentiating. This might be one of the unusual cases where it is easier to solve for $y$ first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either solve for $y$ and differentiate, or you can use implicit differentiation:

$$ \sqrt{xy} = 1 \iff \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}\sqrt{y} + \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{y}} \sqrt{x} \cdot y' = 0$$

by Product rule and chain rule, now you should be able to solve for $y'$

Answer (score 2):

The square root can be ignored, just use $xy=1$. Then you can either differentiate implicitly
$$y+xy'=0\Rightarrow y'=-\frac{y}{x}=-\frac{1}{x^2}=-y^2$$
or express explicitly
$$y=\frac{1}{x}$$
and take the derivative of that.

Comment: [Wolfram's given solution to this question.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dy%2Fdx+for+sqrt%28xy%29+%3D+1)
I don't understand why this differs so greatly from yours.

Comment: @alx The answer in WolframAlpha is the same as this $y'=-\frac{y}{x}$. The expressions $-\frac{1}{x^2}$ and $-y^2$ are alternative forms that are also equal to the solution.